# choosing two not empty groups out of $n$ people

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to choose two not empty groups out of $n$ people?
(each person is different) 
I thought I can maybe do this:
$$\binom{n}{2}\cdot2\cdot2^{n-2}$$
First choose $2$ people to put in each group (and there are two options to put them) and the rest will have two options.
What do you think?

Comment: Are the groups required to be disjoint?  Are the groups distinguishable?

Comment: Hint:  there are three categories of people.  Those in Group $A$, those in group $B$ and those in neither.  ( I am assuming you wanted $A,B$ to be disjoint).  If $A,B$ are not labeled then you have to divide by $2$ to account for the symmetry between them.

Comment: You have a lot of double counting.  The first two people you choose may be in different groups when two other people are chosen first.

Comment: Is everyone suppose to be in one of the two groups?  Your approach suggests that, and it's how I interpret the question, but others apparently do not.

Comment: As you can see from the comments, your question is unclear.  Can you add more detail?  It's always a good idea to work numerical examples.  What do you think the answer is for $n=2$ or $n=3$?  With my interpretation I see $2, 12$ respectively but of course you might have meant something else.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, among your people there is a youngest person.

Choose who else from among all other available people is also in that youngest person's group, noting that it cannot be everyone (*otherwise the other group would be empty*).

If you care about labels on the groups as well, then afterwards, decide which label is used for the group containing the youngest person.

> $(2^{n-1}-1)$ if group labels don't matter, or $(2^{n-1}-1)\times 2$ if labels do matter.

---

As an aside, your answer would have been correct to a *different* but related problem where each group has a designated "leader."  The persons you picked in the first step are being treated differently than those arranged at later steps.

> Picking the leader for the first group, then picking the leader for the second group, then deciding how to split the remaining people in $n(n-1)2^{n-2}$ ways, or if labels on groups don't matter, in $\binom{n}{2}\times 2^{n-2}$